# BoxedAppPacker won't run my x64 executable

Tags: .net, 64-bit

> Summarized version of my problem:

I made a application in .NET which extracts some files to "%TEMP%\Virtuosa Loader\" and when the files are extracted the application launchs a 64 bit process (mame64.exe, which is located at the extracted folder).

Here is the app: http://ElektroStudios.tk/Compiled.exe

The application and the 64 bit process which is launched from the application works perfectly,
But if I pack the application with **BoxedAppPacker** then the 64 bit process will not be launched (mame64.exe).

Here is the packed app using **BoxedAppPacker**: http://ElektroStudios.tk/Packed.exe

I use the default **BoxedAppPacker** options and "**Virtualize all changes of file system and registry**" option 'cause I want to hide the files from the temp dir in all of the ways.

I tried to add/create an empty "**SysWow64**" folder together with the "**system32**" folder in **BoxedappPacker**, I don't know if that was stupid but I don't know what more can I try.

Question: How I can solve the problem please? Why is happening that?

Thankyou for read.

> Extended version of my problem:

I have a **VisualStudio** 2012 project which is targeting Framework 3.0 version and targeting a "AnyCPU" machine, I'm working on Windows 7 x64.

My application basically first of all uses **SevenZipSharp** library to extract a compressed file to the "%TEMP%" folder, when the files inside are extracted then I use "process.start" to launch a procces in the uncompressed folder.

I wrote a method to use sevenzipsharp like this:

```
 SevenZipSharp_Extract(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "\Virtuosa Loader.tmp", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "\Virtuosa Loader\")
```

That line means the content of the file "%TEMP%\Virtuosa Loader.tmp" (Wich is a .7z file with the file-extension changed to .tmp) is extracted to "%TEMP%\Virtuosa Loader\" folder.

Then I change the current working directory and run a process like this:

```
IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "\Virtuosa Loader")
Process.Start("Mame64.exe", "Rom.zip")
```

To finish I use the **BoxedAppPacker** application to pack my compiled project to virtualize all file changes on the system.

The problem is after using **BoxedAppPacker**, when the application that I will launch from my compiled project after the extraction is a x64 executable then It won't start (Any Windows errors, just won't start but the process exists 'cause if i make a simple conditional to check if the file exists it returns True),

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but if instead of a 64 bit executable like "mame64.exe" I try to start a 32 bit executable like "mame.exe" from my compiled and packed application then all works as expected.

I've tried to change the targeting machine in the compile tab of the project settings to x64 and x86, and to pack it with **BoxedappPacker**, if I choose "x64" in the compile tab and I pack my compiled application using **BoxedAppPacker** then the compiled app directly won't run (any windows errors, just won't run)... if i choose "anycpu" or "x86" the packed application run, but the x64 process which iI will launch from my project won't run.

The **BoxedAppPacker** options which I have activated are the default options and this option:
"Virtualize all changes of file system and registry"

...Because I want to virtualize all file changes in the system to not let the users to see the extracted files in the %TEMP% folder, as I said this works perfectly if I pack the app and my packed app launchs a x86 executable, but is not working for x64 executables.

I think this problem is hard to resolve it at least without testing **BoxedappPacker** virtualizer with my project so here are the files:

This is the full VS2012 project file: http://ElektroStudios.tk/Virtuosa_Loader_Project.zip

This is the compiled app: http://ElektroStudios.tk/Compiled.exe

This is the packed app using **BoxedAppPacker**: http://ElektroStudios.tk/Packed.exe

And here is **BoxedAppPacker** trial version: http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/download.html (I'm using the 3.2.3.0 version)

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: I also tried to contact the vendor but unfortunately without any response from they. I have more opportunities to resolve this big problem if I ask to StackOverFlow programming experts like you are, I don't liked that "close this question" reason but thanks for comment!.

Comment: Elektro Hacker, actually I've answered you via the support form :)

Comment: @Artem Razin Yes thankyou for your support, but my problem still not solved, I gived you the two builds .exe but I don't know if you don't saw my message, thankyou anyway again and sorry for my english.